Open a calendar ICS link via Flutter
My server has an endpoint to generate an .ics file (text/calendar) content type.
When I'm trying to open it via launchUrl, I receive the following popup screen - instead of the standard "add to calendar" popup. If I'm using this endpoint directly in my browser (not via Flutter) - it works fine.
This is the code I'm using:
launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://server.com/event.ics'), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);

I'm aware of add_2_calendar and device_calendar, but I don't want to include another dependency here but simply open the normal browser.


The best way that I found, that actually seems to work is to prepend the ics url with this https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cid=webcal://
So with the provided example you would have:
launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cid=webcal://https://server.com/event.ics'), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
This launches the web version of google calendar, and allows subscription.  Every way that I found to open up the android calendar app, didn't end up actually working with the subscription.

Although, I found that this didn't quite work on Android web browsers, but adding a /u/0/ before the r? in the URL did!  Basically because no google apps support the user switching URLs very well, so it has to open in the web.
